# Como ordenar pela classe e por ordem decrescente?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suponha o seguinte banco de dados:

```
set.seed(1)

df_1 <- data.frame(x = replicate(n = 3, expr = sample(x = 1:3, size = 10, replace = TRUE)))
```

Já agora, com o pacote `dplyr` eu tentei:

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 %>% 
  arrange_if(.predicate = desc(is.integer))
```

> Error in x[!nas] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'builtin'

Com `arrange`, `arrange_all` e `arrange_at`, `desc` funciona.

- Como ajustar `arrange_if` para ordem decrescente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, a questão é que você usou dois argumentos de uma vez. O `.predicate`, que só existe nas funções com `_if` é para selecionar as variáveis, então ele deve ter a função que seleciona elas, no caso `is.integer`. E o `.funs` aplica uma função, no caso o `desc`.

```r
set.seed(1)

df_1 <- data.frame(x = replicate(n = 3, expr = sample(x = 1:3, size = 10, replace = TRUE)))

library(dplyr)

df_1
#>    x.1 x.2 x.3
#> 1    1   3   3
#> 2    3   1   1
#> 3    1   1   1
#> 4    2   1   1
#> 5    1   2   1
#> 6    3   2   2
#> 7    3   2   1
#> 8    2   2   1
#> 9    2   3   2
#> 10   3   1   2

df_1 %>% 
  arrange_if(.predicate = is.integer, .funs = desc)
#>    x.1 x.2 x.3
#> 1    3   2   2
#> 2    3   2   1
#> 3    3   1   2
#> 4    3   1   1
#> 5    2   3   2
#> 6    2   2   1
#> 7    2   1   1
#> 8    1   3   3
#> 9    1   2   1
#> 10   1   1   1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: A sintaxe dessas funções com `_if`, `_at` e `_all` é meio confusa mesmo. Na próxima versão do `dply` vai ter uma função `across` que substitui elas e é mais padronizada para uso com outras funções como `mutate` e `summarize`.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, @Jorge. Seguindo ela, verifiquei que a função `across` já está disponível. A quem interessar, basta rodar: `remotes::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")`